# Cannot find JSX Harmony in IntelliJ 2016.2.2 Ultimate Edition

Tags: intellij-idea, reactjs

I have imported a project into IntelliJ 2016.2.2 UE and the developer setup notes for this project state that I need to set the *Javascript language version* to **JSX Harmony**.

But I cannot see it listed as an option.

- Is JSX Harmony the same thing as React JSX?
- If not, how do I get JSX Harmony as an option in IntelliJ?

[image: IntelliJ Settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for "JSX Harmony" to make intellij understand JSX syntax in .js, you can just try using "React JSX" from the dropdown.